# How can I convert seconds to time in Scala?

Tags: scala

```
println("What is the current number of seconds since midnight?")

val s = readInt

val m = (s/60) % 60

val h = (s/60/60) % 24
```

That is my current code. I just do not know how to println("") so it displays in hh:mm form. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer is

```
"%02d:%02d".format(h, m)
```

based on http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/5153

Answer (score 5):

Mostly like @Floris said:

```
val s = System.currentTimeMillis / 1000
val m = (s/60) % 60
val h = (s/60/60) % 24


val str = "%02d:%02d".format(h, m)
// str = 22:40
```

Now you could print it, just like you would with regular string.

Since scala 2.10 there is [string interpolation feature](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html), which allows you to write things like:

```
val foo = "bar" 
println(s"I'm $foo!")
// I'm bar!
```

But I don't think it is much readable (reminds perl):

```
val str = f"$h%02d:$m%02d"
```

Comment: It's arguable if the string interpolation version is readable, but it definitely has the advantage that it's type checked. I.e., if `h` or `m` are not a numeric type (e.g., if they are Strings), the code won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

```scala
// show elapsed time as hours:mins:seconds
val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis/1000

// ... run some code
val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis/1000
var elapsed_s = (t2 - t1)

// for testing invent some time: 4 hours: 20 minutes: 10 seconds 
elapsed_s=4*60*60 + 20*60 + 10

val residual_s = elapsed_s % 60
val residual_m = (elapsed_s/60) % 60

val elapsed_h = (elapsed_s/60/60)

// display hours as absolute, minutes & seconds as residuals
println("Elapsed time: " + "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(elapsed_h, residual_m, 
residual_s))
```