# Play framework convert seconds to time format in scala.html

Tags: html, scala, playframework

Play framework 2.4.4

A html file named "time.scala.html" like this:

```
@(seconds: Long)(session: play.mvc.Http.Session)
<html>
  <head>
   ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h3>Go to sleep at: </h3>
      <h3>????????</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to convert seconds to time format like "HH:MM:SS" use scala, when seconds=75900, display:

```
Go to sleep at: 
21:05:00
```

21:05:00 equal seconds: ((21*60)+5)*60 = 75900

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert seconds to time in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127166/how-can-i-convert-seconds-to-time-in-scala)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer something like:

```
new DateTime(seconds * 1000).toString("HH:mm:ss")
```